# How do I run Ember tests using local Mongo DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, testing, ember.js, yarnpkg

I have set up a local Mongo Database which I initialise as follows:

```
(shell 1)
> mongo
mongo> use prod-db
```

I then start my local server:

```
(shell 2)
> yarn start:server
```

and I then start my ember app:

```
(shell 3)
> yarn start:my-ember-app
```

I now want to write some ember tests and for this I do not want to use `ember-cli-mirage`. I want to use the actual local server I mention above and I also want to use my local Mondo DB, just not the `prod-db` database but a `test-db` one.

In other words I want to do:

```
(shell 1)
> mongo
mongo > use test-db

(shell 2)
> yarn start:server

(shell 3)
> yarn run:ember-tests
```

However, I do not want to do all of the above every time I want to run my ember tests.
I only want to do

```
yarn run:ember-tests
```

And I want the rest (1. starting the local MongoDB using the test-db database 2. starting the local server) to happen "internally" without me having to open up separate shells manually etc..)

Is this possible and how ?

Comment: this end to end testing is a bit out of scope for ember itself, but you could for example run a simple shell script to do it. other people utilize things like docker-compose for this. generally the question is where and when you want to run it? do you need a watch-mode? are you in CI? are you interactive? whats your OS? if you are interactive maybe a script calling tmux could be beneficial, then you would be able to see all the shells. otherwise background services are OK. but the question remains what to do with STDOUT/STDERR.

Comment: So fundamentally you're asking for a new *tool*, and so are IMHO a bit out of scope on SO. So I will vote to close.